# Linking to C++ version of sqrt

Tags: c++, linkage

While code-golfing, I thought that replacing

```
#include<math.h>
```

With (After a previous `#define D double`, since doing so cuts off some characters after using enough doubles)

```
D sqrt(D);
```

Would be less character-expensive. But I found that it didn't link because of the different linkage. Obviously

```
extern "C"{D sqrt(D);}
```

Does the work. But it doesn't help me at all. So, is there some way of linking to a C++ ready version of `sqrt()`?(`-lm` links to the C version in my G++, apparently)

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your Question Can you please Tell Me Some thing more about this?

Comment: I want to link my code to the fuction sqrt(), but I can't do so directly because my G++ has an sqrt() function written with C linkage in the `-lm` library. Specifically: How can I link to a sqrt function written as a C++ one, without using external libraries?(The workaround using `extern "C"` just hides the problem, since g++ should have c++ versions of those functions somewhere... )

Comment: Have you link your math library? if No then try this `g++ <FileName> -lm -o sqr`. For Reference please gop through this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/25362/). Hope this will help you.